# Correlation coefficient in repeated measures linear regression in SAS

Tags: sas, linear-regression, glm

I'm running a random effects linear regression model to determine the relationship between two continuous variables (X and Y) within subjects. I'm currently using `proc glm` in SAS to accomplish this. Where in my output can I find my global regression equation variables?

Example code:

```
proc glm data = Example;
class ID; model Y = X ID X*ID / solution;
random ID;
run;
```

In the results for the solution option, all I can find are the intercept and correlation coefficient for the reference subject, not the whole group.